# Has the DataSource been changed via a BindingSource?

Tags: c#, datasource, bindingsource

I'm using a **BindingSource** to connect a single large data-structure to numerous controls (no SQL, just one data-structure, lots of controls). Old-style Windows Forms application, Visual Studio 2012 Express. I have managed to wrap numerous GUI components with properties to work around the lack of direct support for control binding of things like radio button groups, multi-select listboxes, the title bar, etc. All this works great, updates flow nicely in both directions between the GUI and the data-structure.

I need to track if **any** changes to the data-structure have been made **via any control on the GUI**, but I can't see how to do this (I did look at previous related questions here)... This is needed to provide a simple indication of "changes made but not saved", with an asterisk in the title bar and a warning if the user tries to exit the application without saving changes.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: WPF ? ASP ? Winforms?

Comment: Sorry, old-style Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface from within your object classes, then catch whenever a change occurs through proper event handlers for your type class within your DataSource BindingSource property.

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        class Notifications
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var daveNadler = new Person {Name = "Dave"};
                daveNadler.PropertyChanged += PersonChanged;
            }

            static void PersonChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something changed!");
                Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name = string.Empty;
        private string _lastName = string.Empty;
        private string _address = string.Empty;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this._name; }
            set
            {
                this._name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return this._lastName; }
            set
            {
                this._lastName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return this._address; }
            set
            {
                this._address = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Address");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the documentation - I thought that was only for the currently selected item in the binding list ???

Comment: Also, the documentation seems to say this event is about the metadata, not contents ? Am I misunderstanding the documentation ??

Comment: @DaveNadler - I misunderstood what you were looking for.  This is an example of how to use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  If you hook it up like this you should have no issues detected property changes and saving the relevant properties.

Comment: The BindingSource avoids having to code explicit notification processing for every property in my data-structure. I'm looking for a way to simply trap any change posted through the BindingSource without modifying every property in the single data structure...

Comment: Adding the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to the data-structure's class definition causes binder to stop working (and the notify method is never called)...